# Suppose I know that A implies B, is there a way to use just this information to solve P(C|A)?

Tags: probability, self-study

Let's say I want to find out $P(C=2|B=3)$ but I know that $B=3$ implies that $C\leq3$. Does it mean that I can use $P(C=2|B=3)=P(C=2|C\leq3)$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not quite, because you didn't rule out cases in which $C ≤ 3$ but $B ≠ 3$. You need implications in both directions (an if-and-only-if relationship) in order to substitute conditions like that.

Comment: Yeah, that was what I was thinking too. I just thought I might be missing something. I got so far as $P(C=2|B=3)=P(C=2\cap B=3)/P(C<=3 \cap B=3)$

Comment: I think I got it. I use the fact that $P(C<=3|B=3)=1=P(C=1|B=3)+P(C=2|B=3)+P(C=3|B=3)$ (Note: in the problem, C can only have integer values 1 or higher). So if I can find all times when $C=1,2,3$ under the condition that $B=3$, I got this, right?

Comment: It is not clear to me what you are doing because you haven't defined the sample space or the total possibilities for sets A, B and C.  All you know is that A implies B means B is a subset of A.